# Cannot read properties of undefined Reading 'query'

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando conectar node con mysql, y al ejecutar el metodo 'query' me tira el siguiente error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

Tengo mi archivo de database que realiza la conexion con mysql y lo exporto

```
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(database);
    connection.connect((error)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log('El error de la conexion es: '+error);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Conectado a la base de datos!')
    })
module.exports = connection;
```

Y dentro de mis routes importe el la conexion de la base de datos e intento realizar la query.

```
    connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?",{user:user,
        name:name,
        rol:rol,
        pass:passwordHash})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Te paso un ejemplo de conexión en node, te están faltando los parámetros de la base de datos.

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); // haces el requiere
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'node_mysql',
   port: 3306
}); // Deberías pasar los parámetros de la conexión.
connection.connect(function(error){
   if(error){
      throw error;
   }else{
      console.log('Conexion correcta.');
   }
});
connection.end();
// Abrir base lo mas tarde posible y cerrar lo antes posible.
```

También verifica que tengas tal base de datos creada y corriendo en el pc..

En cuanto a la consulta primero podrías probar algo así:
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (1,2,3)

Luego si todo funcionó ver cómo escapar o hacer uso de placeholders